# Exception when calling Postgresql function returning a local numeric from C#

Tags: postgresql, c#, ado.net

I wrote a Postgresql function to insert a row and return the value generated from the identity column.  I receive the following exception when trying to call it from C#.

Npgsql.PostgresException: '42601: query has no destination for result data'

I have looked around for an answer, and it seems ExecuteScalar has worked for others, but in all the examples I've seen, it's usually when using RETURN QUERY, not a local variable.  What am I missing?

Here is the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.func_insert_item(_name character varying)
 RETURNS BIGINT
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
    _item_id BIGINT;
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO public.items
    (
        name
    )
    VALUES
    (
        _name
    )
    RETURNING _item_id;
    
    RETURN _item_id;
END;
$function$
```

Here is the C#:

```
        static NpgsqlParameter CreateParameter(string name, ParameterDirection direction, string value)
        {
            var parameter = new NpgsqlParameter(name, NpgsqlTypes.NpgsqlDbType.Varchar, value.Length);
            parameter.Direction = direction;
            parameter.Value = value;

            return parameter;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            using var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(connectionString.ToString());
            connection.Open();
            
            using var command = new NpgsqlCommand("func_insert_item", connection);
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            command.Parameters.Add(CreateParameter("_name", ParameterDirection.Input, name));

            object itemId = command.ExecuteScalar();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you misunderstood the `RETURNING` clause. It should list the columns the statement should return, not the names of the variables the returned values should go into. You need an additional `INTO` clause for the latter.

```
CREATE
 OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.func_insert_item(_name character varying)
                     RETURNS bigint
                     LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$$
DECLARE
    _item_id bigint;
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO public.items
                (name)
                VALUES (_name)
                RETURNING <name of the id column>
                          INTO _item_id;
    
    RETURN _item_id;
END;
$$
```

Unfortunately you didn't provide the table's DDL, so I don't know what column could be the ID you want to return. Replace `<name of the id column>` with its name.

Comment: That was it!  Thank you!